# Javascript - getAttribute not working with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html

I want to detect the first letter of the src in an img tag with JavaScript and display an alert if the first letter does not match 'l'  :

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="imgDetect.js"></script>
<img src="l.jpg" />
<img src="a.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName('img').getAttribute('src');
if (x.charAt(0)!=='l'){
window.alert("message")
}
```

The problem is that the `getAttribute` does not work with the`getElementsByTagName`.

The alert will show if `getElementsByTagName` is replaced by `getElementById`, (for only detecting single elements),
I would like it work across all tags in `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `nodelist`. Use it like `x = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src');` or in a `for loop` if you have more than 1 image(which is your case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList object, which is an array like object with reference to multiple elements.

So `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` does not have a method called `getAttribute`, calling that will result in error. Instead you need to iterate through the list and test each element

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].getAttribute('src').charAt(0) !== 'l') {
        window.alert("message")
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wong0n5w/)

---

Also in your script, you have included the script in the page header, which when is executed the body of the pages is not yet loaded so, `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` won't return any elements.

You can use the window's load method to execute your script or move the script to bottom of the page

Using onload

```
window.onload = function () {
    //this part of the script will be executed after the document is loaded completely
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].getAttribute('src').charAt(0) !== 'l') {
            window.alert("message")
        }
    }
}
```

Script at the bottom

```
<img src="l.jpg" />
<img src="a.jpg" />
<script src="imgDetect.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I put 'document.getElementById('errorPage').innerHTML +='image load error';' replacing the alert, it dosen't write to the <p> that has the id.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array. You need to grab the element from the list before further accessing its attributes. Below is the updated code:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  if(images[i].getAttribute('src') !== 'l') window.alert("message");
}
```